# How to customize autofil in Excel

Tags: excel, series

I want to use autofil of MS Excel to make a series that should look like the image shown but it does autofil in its own way, any solution?

[image]

Comment: According to that image, dot `.` is not the decimal delimiter in that Excel. So `0.1` is text for that Excel and it fills it like text. Try determining what is the decimal delimiter in that Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps consider a formula...

```
=ROW(A1)/10
```

and drag down.

[image]

**EDIT:**

To start from 0, change the formula to

```
=(ROW(A1)-1)/10
```

Comment: Is there any way the series can start from 0.0, because there would be some automated code that would be starting this process

Comment: See my revision. Note that @Axel Richter's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54231396/how-to-customize-autofil-in-excel/54231502#comment95288310_54231396) gets to the real issue though. The left alignment of the numbers means they are *text-that-looks-like-numbers*. Numbers should autofill just fine.